# How to make a toolbar button with caption below icon using VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, ribbonx

What's missing in the following code, for the `.Caption` gets bellow and the icon on the top?

```
Sub SoundLogToolbar()
    Dim cb As CommandBar
    Dim de As CommandBar
    Dim but As CommandBarButton
    Dim picPicture As IPictureDisp

    On Error Resume Next
        MkDir "C:\SoundLog\"
    On Error GoTo 0

    On Error Resume Next
        MkDir "C:\SoundLog\Presentations\"
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set picPicture = stdole.StdFunctions.LoadPicture("C:\SoundLog\Presentations\SoundLog.gif")

    On Error Resume Next
        Application.CommandBars("SoundLog").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set cb = Application.CommandBars.Add("SoundLog", msoBarTop, , True)

    Set but = CommandBars("SoundLog").Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
    but.Visible = True
    With but
        .Picture = picPicture
        .OnAction = "ShowUserForm"
        .Caption = "SoundLog!"
        .TooltipText = "run this to get data!"
        .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaptionBelow
    End With

    cb.Visible = True
End Sub
```

With the `msoButtonIconAndCaptionBelow` button style, it wasn't suppose to be like I want?

Comment: I can't see how it can find the picture when you are creating the directory that contains the picture but not copying a gif to the directory.

Comment: ohh, that was copy/past from another sub. Don't botter with it. With this code, the button and toolbar are created but the button has the small icon and the caption at his left. I want to create a button like "New Slide" of ther Powerpoint2007 (a large icon with the caption below) ---> msoButtonIconAndCaptionBelow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely with the picture. You need to use a BMP of 16x16 with 256 colors (see [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288771)). Note you can also set a mask on this for transparency.

From your comment above, however, it looks like you are wanting to do this for PowerPoint 2007. If you are wanting to do this in Office 2007/2010, you shouldn't be using the CommandBar object anymore and rather using the Ribbon technology. Here's a really good article on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163410.aspx). If you're using VBA, the [Custom Ribbon Editor](http://openxmldeveloper.org/articles/customuieditor.aspx) is indispensible and [here's a great landing page](http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2006/12/01/ribbon-example-table-of-contents/) to get you started with RibbonX with VBA (examples are for Excel 2007, but it's the same in PPT/WRD).